How to obtain the heart rate from a EXTERNAL SENSOR in Monkey C
I've tried different codes but all end up in error. I'm using an Edge 820 and my version is 3.1.0
I've tried different codes I found online but none of them worked. I would appreciate if someone could help with my problem :)

Please add the code and the error you are getting. Maybe start with the Sensor example of the SDK.
